# Comparing objects with arrays and return the matched

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Objects

```
{670: true, 671: true}
```

Array

```
0: {id: 669, item_id: 35}
1: {id: 670, item_id: 35}
```

Expected result

```
0: {id: 670, item_id: 35}
```

How could comparing two data and return the matched based on the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want :)

```
let obj = {670: true, 671: true}
let arr = [{id: 669, item_id: 35}, {id: 670, item_id: 35}]
let result = arr.filter(item => obj[item.id])
console.log(result)
```

Result:

```
[
    {id: 670, item_id: 35}
]
```